# SQLite doesn't save data I inserted

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sqlite, sql-insert

I'm messing around with SQL lite and learning it.

I got a table called People, I got some method that connect to the database and do some stuff, like show all the info.

Now I'm trying to insert some data and here it get wierd for me. I have this method:

```
private void ExecuteQuery(string txtQuery)
{
    SetConnection();
    sql_con.Open();
    sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
    sql_cmd.CommandText = txtQuery;
    sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sql_con.Close();
}
```

and to see all the data I've got this method:

```
private void LoadData()
{
    SetConnection();
    sql_con.Open();
    sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
    string CommandText = "SELECT * FROM People";
    DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, sql_con);
    DS.Reset();
    DB.Fill(DS);
    DT = DS.Tables[0];
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
    sql_con.Close();
}
```

When I inset some data and right afther it I call the `LoadData()`, I can see all the changes I made.

After I close the program, and then open it agian and call `LoadData()`, I don't see the new info that I inserted before.

I got some data that I used SQL lite GUI app to insert, and I can see that data every time I call the `LoadData()` method, but not mine.

Do I need to do somthing else to make sure SQL lite saves all the data?

**EDIT: this is how i INSERT the data, mybee the problem is from here?**

```
string insetCommand = "INSERT INTO People Values(2,'" + textBox1.Text + "')";
```

**EDIT2: my connectionString Method**

```
public static string connectionString
    {
        get
        {
            string database =
                //AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "..\\..\\Database\\ImageLib.s3db";
               AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\DataBase\\myTable2";
            string connectionString =
                @"Data Source=" + Path.GetFullPath(database) + ";Version=3;";
            return connectionString;
        }
    }
```

Comment: By any chance, do you have the SQLite database as part of the Visual Studio project?

Comment: i am not sure i understand, how do i check it?

Comment: You should be using a .db3 file (or equivalent) somewhere. Is this included in the VS solution, or are you simply loading it as a separate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem looks as if your data is stored in a temporary database.

Please check that your `connectionString` is actually used (SQLite will use a temporary database if the file name is empty).

To check the database file name from inside your application, execute [`PRAGMA database_list`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_database_list) like a query and check that the third column of the result contains your file name. Example output:

```
> pragma database_list;
seq   name   file
----- ------ ----------
0     main   /tmp/test.db
```

Comment: change the name of my dababase file to myTable2.db and in the connection string too and now it works. thank u!

Comment: wierd, i did a few test and it still not working.  how to i execute the PRAGMA database_list? (i dont know it). thx

Comment: Instead of `string CommandText = "SELECT * FROM People";` use `string CommandText = "PRAGMA database_list";`.

Comment: it return: 0 main C:\Users\roei\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\SmarterSqlLiteTest\SmarterSqlLiteTest\bin\Debug\DataBase\myTable2.db

Comment: There's your file. Check if its time stamp changes after inserting, or if it might be automatically deleted when rebuilding.

Comment: you are right, when i used my own program to make changes in the table, it dosnt even change his time stamp. but when i use another program (data base browser) and do some changes from there, the time stamps changes. what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute a commit statement, i belive that SQLite needs that! You can also try to wrap it all in a transaction!

Comment: as u said i tried do a transction, but i get the same result. i can see the changes in the table when the program work. but, when i close it and then re open it, i cant see the new data i added with the transction. any other ideas?

Comment: When you're not using `BEGIN`/`END TRANSACTION` commands, SQLite will automatically commit after each command.