# what is the exact sytax to open sqlite "Temporary" database using vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlite, temporary

below will create in memory db

```
Dim cn As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=:memory:")
```

below will create disk file db with name abc in C:\Temp\

```
Dim cn As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\Temp\abc")
```

or
below will creates disk file db with name abc at default location ..\SqliteProject\bin\Debug

```
Dim cn As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=abc")
```

but.. how to create temporary db?? [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849679/temporary-in-memory-database-in-sqlite) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997829/difference-between-sqlite-temporary-db-and-inmemory-db) [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849679/temporary-in-memory-database-in-sqlite) [Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438563/sqlite-doesnt-save-data-i-inserted) says "to create temporary db use empty filename". but no one tells the exact code.
I tried various combinations

```
Dim cn As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection("") 
Dim cn As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=") 
Dim cn As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\Temp\")
```

but all throws exception/error

Comment: The file name would nee to be empty. What are the exact errors?

Comment: for first two code lines, it says...
"Data Source cannot be empty.  Use :memory: to open an in-memory database"
for third line, it says...
"Invalid ConnectionString format, cannot parse: unbalanced escape or quote character found"

Comment: Well, "Data Source cannot be empty" is wrong. Unless there is some other mechanism to specify a temporary database, this appears to be a bug in whatever SQLite driver you're using.

Comment: i downloaded "sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x64-2013-1.0.99.0.exe" from here... http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki
 (it is still on the webpage) 

after excuteing the setup

I referenced this dll.
..\bin\Debug\System.Data.SQLite_DLL\2013\bin\System.Data.SQLite.dll. its version is 1.0.99.0 and Run time version is v4.0.30319

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Data.SQLite uses the following code to check the database name:

```
  fileName = FindKey(opts, "Data Source", DefaultDataSource);

  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
  {
    fileName = FindKey(opts, "Uri", DefaultUri);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
    {
      fileName = FindKey(opts, "FullUri", DefaultFullUri);
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        throw new ArgumentException(UnsafeNativeMethods.StringFormat(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Data Source cannot be empty.  Use {0} to open an in-memory database", MemoryFileName));
```

So it is not possible to specfiy an empty name.

However, it is possible to specify a URI filename with an empty path:

```
New SQLiteConnection("FullUri=file:")
```

Comment: “CL” thanks for yours solution it really helped me. but my actual problem is there... as it is. I posted it as an Question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551758/how-to-control-sqlite-in-memory-consumption-using-c-sharp-vb-net